# Implementing Principal Component Analysis in Azure ML Studio

Tags: machine-learning, pca, predictive-models, internet

After applying Principal Component Analysis PCA to my data set in order to achieve better model accuracy. The 13 features dimensions, I am reducing it to 10 features using PCA. Everything is fine till here.

After implementing the model in WebApp, it is building & seems fine in the studio.

In the testing phase of model prediction, Instead of displaying 10 features as an input, the UI system is showing the original features which is 13 & the output is showing 10 features which does not have any feature names for the newly generated features which are 10. And also prediction is not working at all after executing it.

Attached are the screenshots, Please refer.enter image description here

Comment: Welcome to site, is there a statistical or data analysis part to your question? You may not of privilege to post your question, so you may have to summarize it in the question.